# No data coming from the perfmon statistic SQL Server: Replication Dist

Tags: sql-server, replication, performance-monitoring

I am trying to get the statistics from my 2008 sql server replication SQL Server: Replication Dist. statistics, but no data is coming even while replication is in full swing.

I am using SQL 2008 peer-to-peer replication and use a load test on our web site to generate the load on the database that is replicated.

There are no errors coming from Replication Monitor and the Latency on the publication is showing and changes between 0 and 3 seconds during the test.

We are monitoring the statistics for the distributor at both ends of the peer-to-peer replication.

Is there something I need to do to get SQL to start publishing the stats?

note: I have added a second publication using a snapshot model and that causes stats to be generated. Does SQL not record latency for peer-to-peer?

Comment: Are you monitoring the publisher, the subscriber or the distributor?

Comment: Peer to peer replication, monitoring on both nodes (i.e. at publisher and subscriber). The distributor is the item measured by the statistic.

Answer (score 1):

is the server running as a default instance? if not then look for the perfmon object that is in the form of *MSSQL$instancename:Replication Dist.*

Answer (score 0):

Each subscription creates it's own group of instances under the perfmon category. Be aware that SQL keeps instances of previously deleted subscriptions, so make sure you are measuring the correct instance, especially when tearing down and recreating subscriptions.